# Is there a way to improve the speed of combining two values as strings?

Tags: python, pandas, string, large-data

I am currently working with a very large dataset (>70mil rows, 10+ columns), it involves gap fills, forwards fills, reindexing, etc. But the step that takes the most time (over 50% of run time) is the simple code of replacing a column variable with the value of two columns combined as strings. Example code would be:

```
df["id_date"] = df['id'].astype(str) +"_"+ df["date"].astype(str)
```

Is there a way to improve the speed of this step? I am surprised this takes such a great deal longer than what thought would be more complex steps.

Comment: Try numpy.char.add for vectorized string concatenation. It’s slow because it’s essentially a Python for loop under the hood.

Comment: I was thinking a loop under the hood had to be the culprit. I'll give numpy a try. Thanks.

Comment: Well, for starters, `df['id'].astype(str)` creates a new, length 70mil series, `df['id'].astype(str) +"_"` creates a *another one*, and finally, `+ df["date"].astype(str)` creates two more, including the last one, which gets assigned to the column. So four 70 million+ rows are created (not to mention the one that gets made internally in the dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`Series.str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
df['id_date'] = df['id'].str.cat(df["date"], sep='_')
```

That being said, as with any redundant information, you are likely better off just not having this column, or at least only creating the data on demand instead of up front.